# How do I find out the Top N diseases according to the cost of their treatment?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-warehouse

This is what I've tried so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    RECORDS.TOTAL_COST, DISEASE.DISEASE_ID
FROM 
    RECORDS, DISEASE
WHERE 
    DISEASE.DISEASE_ID = RECORDS.DISEASE_ID 
    AND TREATMENT.TREATMENT_ID = RECORDS.TREATMENT_ID
GROUP BY 
    DISEASE.DISEASE_NAME
```

This is the star schema for the data provided

`Treatment` table

```
CREATE TABLE treatment
(
    treatment_id NUMBER(6),
    treatment_type VARCHAR2(30),
    private_cost NUMBER(8,2),
    public_cost NUMBER(8,2),
    description VARCHAR
)
```

Create the records fact table

```
CREATE TABLE records
(
    patient_id NUMBER(6),
    doctor_id NUMBER(6),
    disease_id NUMBER(6),
    treatment_id NUMBER(6),
    time_id DATE,
    side_effects NUMBER(1),
    effectivness NUMBER(1),
    total_cost NUMBER(8,2)
 );
```

Create foreign keys to all dimensional tables

```
ALTER TABLE records
ADD ( CONSTRAINT records_patients_fk FOREIGN KEY (patient_id) REFERENCES patients,
 CONSTRAINT records_doctors_fk FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES doctors,
 CONSTRAINT records_disease_fk FOREIGN KEY (disease_id) REFERENCES disease,
 CONSTRAINT records_treatment_fk FOREIGN KEY (treatment_id) REFERENCES treatment,
 CONSTRAINT records_times_fk FOREIGN KEY (time_id) REFERENCES times); 

CREATE TABLE disease
(
    disease_id NUMBER(6),
    disease_name VARCHAR2(30) 
);
```

Comment: You are close, use `order by desc` on `Total cost` and use `LIMIT  N` to get `top N` OR You can use the `RowNum` also to get top n

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data returned in the first query is mostly correct aside from wanting only the top N items:

```
SELECT TOTAL_COST, DISEASE_ID
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT RECORDS.TOTAL_COST, DISEASE.DISEASE_ID
   FROM RECORDS, DISEASE
   WHERE DISEASE.DISEASE_ID=RECORDS.DISEASE_ID AND
   TREATMENT.TREATMENT_ID=RECORDS.TREATMENT_ID
   GROUP BY DISEASE.DISEASE_NAME
   ORDER BY RECORDS.TOTAL_COST DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5; -- replace 5 with however many you want.
```